# Extract rails db to JSON file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sqlite, dump, ruby-on-rails-4

**How can I extract the data in the rails sqlite3 db to a file?**

I'm using rails 4.

I would like to extract all the data in my database so I can reload it later when I reset my database, or when I switch to a different type of db.

Comment: Why don't you simply take db dump?

Comment: replied below as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "yaml_db" gem.   https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

```
rake db:data:dump
```

to dump data
(Data is stored in a seperate file after dumping)
and

```
rake db:data:load
```

to load data to other database

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with `.dump` instead of generating a json dump. But only for curiosity I wrote a script to convert all models into json.

```
Rails.application.eager_load! # To load all models app/models/**/*.rb

all_records = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map &:all

all_records.to_json
```

But it probably will take so long to perform in a real environment with many records.

**Another way (which I recommend for this case)** as the Sqlite3 is only a file, just copy the file `db/development.sqlite3` to  `db/development.sqlite3.backup`. When you want to recover it, just copy it back `cp -f db/development.sqlite3.backup db/development.sqlite3`. Remember that the `.dump` generates an ASCII text file with the inserts and creates statements, you can't recover it in the database which it was extracted, because it will attempt to duplicate the records.

Comment: This is much better than dabbling with javascript or sqlite3 commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple write this line in **seeds.rb**

```
File.open("post.json", "w") { |f| f.write Post.all.to_json }
```

here `Post` should be replaced with your model's name.
then run in terminal:

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a DB dump file of your database and use it when you want.

Assuming you want to dump the database for `db/development.sqlite3`, 
this is straight from the [Sqlite3 Help](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html):

> Use the "`.dump`" command to convert the entire contents of a database
>   into a single ASCII text file. This file can be converted back into a
>   database by piping it back into sqlite3.

To create the dump file:

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 | gzip -c > dev.dump.gz
```

To restore the dump file:

```
zcat dev.dump.gz | sqlite3 development.sqlite3
```

Comment: You are not operating a remote machine, right? `sqlite3` must be there as a gem in your current Rails project directory if you are using it in your project

Answer (score 0):

i used to extract all db to json using userfriendly phpmyadmin export. it create easily export json data for your database. hope this will help you.

goto phpmyadmin

export / type json